# Need bank details for inApppurchase test

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have to add in app purchase in my application.

and for testing i just want to confirm that should i need to add my bank info ?

I just want to know that is my  bank details is necessary if i am only testing and not sending it to appstope?
[here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/116.0.9.9.14.9.3)

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to add your bank info. Apple will review your bank details and approve your in-app purchase. This will take few days.

Comment: I do not want to submit it to apple...
just for testing  ?

Comment: You have to. Thats the apple procedure

Comment: oh...thank you

can you contact me on skype my id is ranjeet.cssoft
i need some more help

Comment: You don't need to submit your app, only your bank and US tax info.

Comment: @CpnCrunch Yes we don't need to submit the app. I just read the answer again, it was wrongly conveyed. I try to convey submitting the bank details.

Answer (score -1):

No!

You don't need to enter your bank details. In iTunes Connect, create a new user. This is your test user. You can create as many as you want.

Then, on your test device, go to Settings and log out of the App Store.

In your app, select to buy the in-app purchase. You will be prompted for some credentials. Enter your test user's credentials. This will allow you to buy the in-app purchase without using your own account.

Good luck. It is a bit fiddly getting it all working. I'll post the link to the tutorial that I used when I can.

Comment: Please post the link  i am still waiting for any solution

Comment: That info is incorrect. You definitely do need to enter banking/tax info before you can test in-app purchases even in the sandbox. If you don't have any banking/tax info set up you will just get "invalid product ID".

Answer (score -1):

This is the tutorial that I used. Goes through everything very clearly.

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: No, it doesn't mention that you have to set up tax/banking info, which is required.